# Isomorphism in localization of rings

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, localization, ring-isomorphism

I have faced some problem while cross with them in localization of ring.
$1)$ Give examples of distinct proper ideals $I$ and $J$ of a ring $R$ and a multiplicative subset $S$ of $R$ such that $S^{-1}I=S^{-1}J$.

$2)$ Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1≠0$. $S$ be the set of all units of $R$. Then show that $f:R→S^{-1}R$ is an isomorphism.

$3)$ Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1≠0$. Let $x∈R$ and $S=\bigl\{1,x,x^2,x^3,.........\bigr\}$. Then show that $S^{-1}R$ is isomorphic to $R(Y)/(xY-1)$.

After thinking enough I can do only first one by taking $R=Z$ and $S=$ set of all odd integers and $I=14Z$ and $J=6Z$.

Is my answer of the $1$st question correct?
Please help me to solve the others.

Comment: Your example is correct. For the second and third one use the universal property of localization. This will induce a map. Then check that this is actually an isomorphism.

Comment: Sorry sir, I tried so far for the third one but failed. @Krish

Comment: I take  $f:R(Y)→S^{-1}R$ by the assignment $Y→1/x$ for any $f(y)∈R(Y)$ where $f(y)=a_1y^1+a_2y^2+.....+a_ny^n$.   I can not proceed further.   @Krish

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For question $3)$, the isomorphism is with $/(xY-1)$. $R(Y)$ isn't really defined  if $R$ is not an integral domain.

This isomorphism can be defined this way: first consider the ring homomorphism:
\begin{align}
\varphi\colon R[Y]&\longrightarrow R_x\\
Y&\longmapsto\varphi(Y)=\frac1x
\end{align}
and check $\;\ker\varphi$ is the principal ideal generated by $xY-1$.

*Some details*:

Let $P(Y)\in R[Y]$ such that $P(\frac1x)=0$ in $R_x$, and consider the canonical image of $P(Y)$ in $R_x[Y]$: since $\frac1x$ is a root, it is divisible by $Y-\frac1x$ in this polynomi

Comment: I go through like you but failed sir. Is my way is correct what I have mentioned in the above comment? @Bernard